# Eclipse fragment not resoving classes in parent plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-fragment

Running in Linux on Eclipse Mars.2. I am using a targetplatform so that the plugins are mostly from Kepler.2, due to one of my plugins being 3rd party from that era.

I have a fragment that will not compile in Eclipse because lots of classes do not resolve. I see no reason why this should be as fragment.xml and MANIFEST.MF in the fragment look fine. Of course the host fragment is unaware of the fragment.

build.properties of the fragment

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
           .,\
           fragment.xml,\
           icons/
```

fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<fragment>
   <extension
         point="org.drools.eclipse.menueventhandler">
      <handler
            class="com.example.drools.eclipse.events.menu.BPMN2EditorMenuEventHandler">
      </handler>
   </extension>
     <extension
           point="org.drools.eclipse.editparteventhandler">
        <handler
              class="com.example.drools.eclipse.events.editpart.ETLPartEventHandler"></handler>
     </extension>
</fragment>
```

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test Drools Eclipse
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.ui.drools.eclipse;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: Test
Fragment-Host: org.drools.eclipse;bundle-version="5.2.0.YR"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.ide
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This I think, was a consequence of refactoring a package name in the host plugin. It looks like it did not refactor the name in the visible packages, but just removed it. I am guessing here as previously it compiled fine and one of the few changes I made was this refactoring of package name. When I added back the 2 packages as being visible it compiled again.